# How to update "th:field" in Thymeleaf form?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I'm making a Spring MVC app using Thymeleaf.

The app contains a Combo Box/Dropdown Menu inside a form. I want every selected value in the Combo Box to be linked to the update of specific fields. I.e.

- `value 1` -> form updates `field 1`
- `value 2` -> form updates `field 2`
- ...

I tried by changing the value of `th:field` using JavaScript, but looks like Thymeleaf tags are "pre-processed" and once the HTML is rendered and the form is associated with a specific field, it stays like that.

What would be the best way to face this problem?

Would it be necessary to trigger the refreshment of the page every time that the value of the Combo changes so that the field that the form updates can vary or there's a better way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Like you mention, it's not possible to change "th:field" or any thymeleaf-specific attributes after the page has been rendered.

However, "th:field" is usually just a shortcut for setting the "id", "name", and "value" attributes. (See here: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#inputs) So you could update those manually from your Javascript.

Although in this case I think the simplest solution would be to create a new type of object in your Java code with fields that match the fields of your form, and use that object instead. So, for example:

```java
class MyFormDTO {

    private String fieldToUpdate;
    private String newValue;

    // ... getters and setters ...
    
}
```

And in your template:

```html
<select th:field="*{fieldToUpdate}">
    <option value="field1">Field1</option>
    <option value="field2">Field2</option>
</select>

<input type="text" th:field="*{newValue}" />
```

And your POST handler method:

```java
@PostMapping("/my-form")
public String submitMyForm(MyFormDTO myFormDTO) {
    MyBackendObject myBackendObject = MyBackendService.get(...);

    switch (myFormDTO.getFieldToUpdate()) {
        case "field1": myBackendObject.setField1(myFormDTO.getNewValue()); break;
        case "field2": myBackendObject.setField2(myFormDTO.getNewValue()); break;
    }
}
```

...rather than using the "MyBackendObject" (or whatever) directly as the form object.

Comment: I ended up taking a different approach. Turned out that using multiple fields was redundant, thus I refactored so that the updated field was unique. Your answer is really good though, and helped me to came up with this solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem! Good luck with your project